# Running Linux command after reboot under specific conditions

Tags: command-line, boot, script, ubuntu-18.04, kubernetes

we are currently setting up a Kubernetes Cluster.
Kubernetes starts up at server boot normally and after a while, after the program "kubelet" has fully loaded its components, the network port 30000 opens up. Takes up to 20 seconds.

Only when 30000 is open, I can run a port forwarding command. Not earlier.

I tested the command manually, no problems here. Working like a charm.

But since I want that port forwarding command to run automatically (and with root privileges), I am now wondering how to archieve this.

Somehow putting the command into a script, somehow running that script at boot time, somehow waiting for port 30000 to show up...

I know of course how to check manually, if port 30000 is open (netstat, telnet, lsof... see here https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/). But how can I do that programmatically?
Sorry, I have never written Linux shell scripts before.

Btw: I am using Ubuntu Server 18.04 as virtual machine for this.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!
Greetings!

Comment: Could you run a script at bootup that checks whether the port is open. If open, run command. If not, check again? I mean like a loop to check the port and if the condition is met, then run the command and exit loop?

Comment: @padawan_IT I know that. But how can it be run on boot time?

Comment: You could use the cronjob: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

@Reboot is the option you are looking for.